# My Middleware is working in protecting routes but not working properly after successful login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with my codes. I'm encountering something my classmates can't fix. Here's the problem:

I have my middleware working properly in protecting routes. After I successfully login it redirects me to my leader.blade.php, in my leader.blade.php, I have a navbar that contains different blades, but after I click one of those navigations, my system redirects me to login again.

I don't know why I was redirected again to my login page while I have a successful login. I think, theres a problem with my remember me func' or cookies or crsf_token, I don't know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class notLeader
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!($request->user['acclvl'] == 'Leader' || $request->user['acclvl'] == 'Leader')) {
            return redirect('/login');
        }


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

here's my Middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'isLeader']], function () {
    Route::resource('announces-admin', 'AnnouncementController@annadmin');
});
```

here's my routes (for testing only)

```
<section class="col-lg-12 connectedSortable">


          <div class="box">




           <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
              <h2 class="box-title">Announcements</h2>
              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button onclick="window.location.href='/announce'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="New Announcement"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
              <!--   <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button> -->
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table no-margin">
                  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                  <tbody>  @foreach ($data as $row) 
                  <tr>


                      <h2 style="color: #00a3cc;">{{ $row->subject }}</h2>
                      <h5>Posted by:   <b style="color:#008CBA;">{{ $row->poster }}</b>, {{ $row->created_at }}</h5>
                      <p style="font-size:1.20em;font-weight:450;" class='item test'>{{ $row->message }}</p>
                      <span class="more_text">
                        <a href="{{ url('viewspec', $row->id )}}" class="read_more"> <br>Continue Reading >></a><br><hr>
                      <br>

                  </tr>  @endforeach

                </tbody>
                </table>{!! $data->render() !!}
              </div><!-- /.table-responsive -->
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->

        </section><!-- /.Left col -->
```

here's my announces-admin.blade.php (which is in my navbar at leader.blade.php)

Comment: I assume that your isLeader middleware is responsible for creating fields like $request->user['acclvl']? And in your routes.php only one resource is using that middleware, could it be that other links don't have this middleware, therefore don't get this object and therefore get redirected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (add `use Auth;` at the top if the middleware)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->acclvl != 'Leader') {
                return redirect('/login');
            }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: thanks sir for your answer .. i'll try this code .. thanks a lot